# Lubuntu Virtualbox Dual Monitor Maximize Issue

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, lxqt

I am running Lubuntu 22.04 in VirtualBox 6.1.38 on Windows 10 Host. I am successfully able to setup dual monitor by including GuestAdditions. But when I try to open and maximize a window (for example: File Manager) it maximizes across both screens. Is this normal in Lubuntu? How can I maximize on single monitor only so that I can work with 2 maximized windows on each screen.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you maximize `pcmanfm-qt` it will maximize only to a single monitor, but I suspect your issue is the VM setup you're using, which likely has a single monitor (as seen by Lubuntu) being shown on two of your monitors.  Providing a screen capture (*via link or added to your question*) would have been helpful, including how you setup your monitors (ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.10/monitor_settings.html)

Comment: In VM setup I have already set monitor count to 2. And yes I tried "pcmanfm-qt" but same result.

Comment: You've setup monitor count to 2 in *LXQt Monitor Settings* -- where? how?   I don't see any reference in the manual link I provided to allow for that; nor link to where I can see how you setup your LXQt system as requested.

Comment: Monitor count is there in VirtualBox Settings-->Display. In LxQt Monitor Settings, it detects both monitors and I can successfully enable/disable both of them.

Comment: Alright, logging out and logging in seems to fix the issue but we wouldn't want to do it every single time we start the system.